# Visual C++ arithmetic with `const` slower than regular variable

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, constants

So I was messing with Visual C++ 2015, and I noticed that there's an issue with the way Visual C++ seems to compile constants and the accessing of them.

Consider the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define ITERATIONS 500000
#define GET_START_TIME QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
#define GET_END_TIME QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
#define CALC_DIFF_TIME ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart; ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000; ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

int main()
{
    short results[ITERATIONS];
    const int n = 5;
    int m = 5;
    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);

    // This loop seems to take about 1400 us on my computer.
    printf("Beginning loop over %i iterations with n constant.\n", ITERATIONS);

    GET_START_TIME;

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        int statement = i % 10;

        if (statement == 0)
            results[i] = n * 0;
        else if (statement == 4)
            results[i] = n * 4;
        else if (statement == 2)
            results[i] = n * 2;
        else if (statement == 5)
            results[i] = n * 5;
        else if (statement == 7)
            results[i] = n * 7;
        else if (statement == 6)
            results[i] = n * 6;
        else if (statement == 1)
            results[i] = n * 1;
        else if (statement == 3)
            results[i] = n * 3;
        else if (statement == 9)
            results[i] = n * 9;
        else if (statement == 8)
            results[i] = n * 8;
    }

    GET_END_TIME;
    CALC_DIFF_TIME;

    printf("Finished in %lld us.\n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart);

    // This one takes about 800 us on my computer.
    printf("Beginning loop over %i iterations with m variable.\n", ITERATIONS);

    GET_START_TIME;

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        int statement = i % 10;

        if (statement == 0)
            results[i] = m * 0;
        else if (statement == 4)
            results[i] = m * 4;
        else if (statement == 2)
            results[i] = m * 2;
        else if (statement == 5)
            results[i] = m * 5;
        else if (statement == 7)
            results[i] = m * 7;
        else if (statement == 6)
            results[i] = m * 6;
        else if (statement == 1)
            results[i] = m * 1;
        else if (statement == 3)
            results[i] = m * 3;
        else if (statement == 9)
            results[i] = m * 9;
        else if (statement == 8)
            results[i] = m * 8;
    }

    GET_END_TIME;
    CALC_DIFF_TIME;

    printf("Finished in %lld us.\n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The top section runs *slower* (by about 75% extra time) than the bottom section, and the only difference is that `n` is a `const int` instead of a regular `int`.

My questions: is this by design, or a flaw/bug in Visual C++? Does this have to do with the fact that I am assigning the result to a `short`?

After further debugging, it seems that if I change the `short` array to an `int` array, then the speed for the regular variable increases from ~800us to 1400us with the `const` value.

So an additional question: why does it take *longer* for the regular variable arithmetic result to be assigned to an `int` array, than a `short` array, and why does the `const int` take the same amount of time for either?

---

Additional notes: further troubleshooting revealed that this only happens in Release mode, not in Debug mode.

I've included the `.asm` file [on Gist](https://gist.github.com/EBrown8534/44ae3aeaab0ec0f15f8d) for anyone interested.

Comment: Can you show the disassembly?

Comment: @Mysticial I have no idea how to get it, care to enlighten me?

Comment: It's buried in one of the preferences. I don't VS in front of me at the moment and I can't name the option name off the top of my head. So you'll have to look around. IIRC, it's probably under "output files".

Comment: Do timings stay the same if you swap the loops i.e. run the "fast" loop first?

Comment: @dxiv Mostly, the constant loop runs *slightly* faster, but it's still 20% longer than the variable loop.

Comment: @Mysticial I found the Disassembly window, but it doesn't show me the disassembly for the if statements, only for the main loop.

Comment: If it's 20% slower now (vs. 75% originally) that's more than "slightly". You'll probably need to check the disaassembly for the remaining difference. Also, do timings change if you change 'results' to 'static short results'? Just curious if that 1 MB array on the stack matters speed-wise.

Comment: @EBrown You're looking at the wrong thing. There's a compiler option that makes the computer output and save the assembly for the entire program. You'll want to configure that output assembly with source so you can actually find what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mysticial Ah, I just found the compiler option and I have the `.asm` file. I've dropped it on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/EBrown8534/44ae3aeaab0ec0f15f8d).

Comment: @dxiv Yes, marking the array as `static` makes the execution time more than quadruple, and the constant version is faster.

Comment: The compiler completely took out all those branches. So you're actually benchmarking an empty loop. What you're seeing is the difference of how empty the loop is.

Comment: @Mysticial I suppose that makes sense, but why would the loop with the regular variable be *more* empty than the loop with the constant?

Comment: @Mysticial indeed. I suppose replacing "return 0;" with "return results[ITERATIONS / 2];" would be enough to convince the compiler that "results" is in fact used.

Comment: @dxiv I just added some `printf` statements to print some of the `results` and it looks like both loops took exactly the same amount of time. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Looking at the machine code is important to see what is happening.  *Very* little of your code remains after the optimizer is done with it, the result[] assignments are all removed since they don't have any observable side-effects and the `n` and `m` identifiers never get used.  All that remains is the code for `i % 10`.  Which is optimized to a multiplication, much faster on Intel cores.  It uses two different strategies for some reason, one is signed and the other is unsigned.  You are seeing that the unsigned version is slightly faster.

Comment: thanks but @Mysticial got the first look at the assembly and pointed the issue. The answer is his for the taking.

Comment: @HansPassant This happens to be an AMD Phenom II this is running on, but I love the explanation there. :)